# Need to strip <a> anchor tags from <img> tags but leave other <a> tags unscathed (using PHP)

Tags: php, rss, image

I am building a RSS feed for a client and they require that  tags not be embedded in an  anchor tag.

Sample below:

```
<a href="http://www.xxxx.us/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/image47.png">
<img     style="background-image: none; margin: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-right:    0px; display: inline; padding-top: 0px; border: 0px;" title="image" src="http://www.xxxx.us/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/image_thumb46.png" alt="image" width="244" height="175" border="0" />
</a>
```

I can't use $content = stip_tags($content); since that will strip all anchor tags

Comment: use DOM. some xpath to find all `<img>` that are children of `<a>` and some tree manipulation to remove the `<a>` and you're done.

Comment: I am trying to work on a regex php way of solving the problem

Comment: do **NOT** use regexes to handle html. That's an automatic million downvotes on this site. You'll spend 80% of your time trying to get the regex to work, 19% of the time ripping out your hair, and 1% calling suicide hotlines.

Answer (score 0):

strip_tags() has the ability to allow tags which aren't stripped.

see the following example

```
<?php
$text = '<p>Test paragraph.</p><!-- Comment --> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>';
// Allow <p> and <a>
echo strip_tags($text, '<p><a>');
?>
```

or the manual
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: Yes, but I need to keep "some" <a> tags and just remove the <a> tags that surround images.